# Regex using notepad++ to delete and replace text

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I'm trying to use regex to replace and delete some text on existing code.

Here is sample of my text

```
01;TEST;Delete;Delete;Delete;keep||
```

So far I was able to replace the number and test to new text using `^\d+\;` but I would like to delete 3 texts after words and keep the 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex in Find what:

```
^(\d+);([^;]+);[^;]+;[^;]+;[^;]+;(.*)$
```

And this expression in Replace with:
    \1\2\3

Here `\1` will capture a number, `\2` - a text next to it (TEST in your example), `\3` - anything after the last "Delete". You can put any other text instead of `\2` or `\3`, of course.

Comment: awesome thanks :) last question how about when deleting the ||

Comment: Great answer except I had a hard time deciphering _why_ it worked. This, of course, fails with any variants, so to explain it better, each \number (\1,\2,\3) looks for blocks of the regex, denoted by parentheses. Notice there are only 3 parts surrounded by them, even though it's not necessary.